# Drupal 8 Routing - Parameters to _controller

Tags: drupal, controller, routes, drupal-8

my_module.content:
path: '/admin/my_module/{method}'
defaults:
_controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleController::%{method}' // Not working

How can I send a a parameter to the _controller? to switch between the methods of the controller

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the routing you have something like this

```
example.content:
  path: '/example' 
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content' 
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content'
```

To give params from the URL:

> Add a variable you want to receive in the controller later.
>   NOTICE: **path: '/example/{id_param}'**

```
example.content:
  path: '/example/{id_param}' 
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content' 
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Now, in the controller:

You'll have something like this

```
function content($id_param) {
  echo($id_param);
}
```

That prints whatever you pass to the URL. For example yourdrupalsite.com/example/**1920**

Prints

> 1920

Comment: Have to mention that the two variable has to be identical

Answer (score 1):

Passing parameter to form :

```
MODULE_NAME.contactform_results:
  path: '/contactform/results/{PARAMETER}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Contact Form Submissions'
    _form: '\Drupal\MODULE_NAME\Form\TicketSendingForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access control'
```

Then in form builder function

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $PARAMETER = null) {
      echo ($PARAMETER);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to cast the parameter to an entity (fx. an ID), be aware that the parameter can't have underscores  - alternatively use camelcase.

```
example.entity:
  path: '/entity/{entityName}'
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content' 
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content' 
  options:
    parameters:
      entityName:
        type: entity:entity_name
```